# Python Appending Dictionaries within function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm trying to understand how functions work, I created a function that takes 2 dictionaries as arguments and returns 1 single dictionary. When I run the function it works as expected and returns the full dictionary. The purpose of the function is to iterate over a for loop and drop the data in *y*

```
def testing_dict(x, y):
    y = {**x, **y}
    return y

x = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
y = {}

testing_dict(x, y)

Out: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

but if I run *y* I get an empty dictionary, when I want is to store all the values from x

```
y
Out: {}
```

Comment: You return `y`. You don't update the global variable. Try `y = testing_dict(x, y)`

Comment: work like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Moving comment to answer)

In your function, you are setting a local variable `y` which is not the same as the global `y` defined outside the function.

To access the local value, there are two options:

► Use the return value of the function to set the global variable:

```
y = testing_dict(x,y)  # get return value
```

► Update the global variable from the function:

```
def testing_dict(x, y):
    global y  # access global variable
    y = {**x, **y}  # set global variable
    return y
```